# Parametrize test function with fixture results if they're a list

Tags: python, dynamic, pytest, fixtures

I would like for my fixtures to parametrize whatever context calls them with that fixture's result if it is a list. Ideally, I won't have to use the `pytest_generate_tests` method to procedurally parametrize these functions.

For example, given this object:

```
class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def get_1(self):
        return '{0}-1'.format(self.name)

    def get_a(self):
        return '{0}-a'.format(self.name)

    def get_each(self):
        return [x*3 for x in self.name]
```

And this `conftest.py` file:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=['bob', 'joe', 'fred'])
def main_fixture(request):
    test_obj = MyObject(request.param)
    return test_obj


@pytest.fixture
def use_1(main_fixture):
    uses_1 = main_fixture.get_1()
    return uses_1


@pytest.fixture
def use_a(main_fixture):
    uses_a = main_fixture.get_a()
    return uses_a


@pytest.fixture
def use_get_each(main_fixture):
    uses_get_each = main_fixture.get_each()
    return uses_get_each
```

And these test functions:

```
class TestMyObject(object):

    def test_myobject_use_1(self, use_1):
        assert use_1[-1] == '1'

    def test_myobject_use_a(self, use_a):
        assert use_a[-1] == 'a'

    def test_myobject_use_get_each(self, use_get_each):
        assert type(use_get_each) is not list
```

The first two tests pass (use_1 and use_a) but the final test does not because the fixture `use_get_each` returns a list of those values. I would like for the failing test function to be parametrized with each of the results in that list.

Something like this (not valid pytest code but demonstrates what I'm trying to accomplish):

```
@pytest.fixture(params=['bob', 'joe', 'fred'])
def main_fixture(request):
    test_obj = MyObject(request.param)
    return test_obj


@pytest.fixture
def use_get_each(request, main_fixture):
    uses_get_each = main_fixture.get_each()
    return uses_get_each

# this fixture is parametrized with the output of the use_get_each fixture
# so that its params look like the following after the fixture is evaluated:
# params=['bbb', 'ooo', 'bbb', 'jjj', 'ooo', ...] instead of
# params=[['bbb', 'ooo', 'bbb'], ['jjj', 'ooo', 'eee'], ...]
@pytest.fixture(params=use_get_each)
def uses_use_get_each(request):
    return request.param
```

I understand that there is a proposal in for a feature like this that can be found [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/proposals/parametrize_with_fixtures.html). So I guess what I'm looking for are potential solutions to this that I have not already explored which includes pretty much `pytest_generate_tests` only.